# Asp MVC3 Custom EditorTemplate for Collections (Empty or Not)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, collections, editortemplates

After much googling, stackoverflowing (?) and blog-reading I still cant completely solve the issue. Hopefully this experts community can come to the rescue!

Given:
A Company class with a field ICollection (A Company can have many addresses). Each adress has a few simple string fields.

### Short Version:

I want the user to be able to add any number of addresses to the company. First I want to show one set of Address textboxes and then a "Add one more address" button. The Javascript is no problem, rather the mvc part. If unclear, the functionality should be similair to this:
http://www.mdelrosso.com/sheepit/index.php?lng=en_GB&sec=demo3

I need to use the MVC EditorForModel() function, which means all configuration needs to go in editor templates.

### Status so far:

- Created ViewModel for the edit company page (CompanyViewModel)
- Added [UIHint("Addresses")] to the field public ICollection Addresses { get; set; }
- Created Addresses EditorTemplate

In the Addresses EditorTemplate, when adding a new Company, the model passed in is Null (no surprises there). How do I create the editor for the extra address? I tried multiple incarnations of (using Razor):

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => new Address());
```

but aint able to produce anything even remotely working. (The exact above line gives the error "Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.")

Thanks for any pointers!

/Victor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a shortcoming of the current APIs. One way you could do it is to have a child action that's responsible for generating the insert form

In your controller:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult AddAddress() {
    return View(new Address()); // pass an instance so view works
}
```

Add a new view `AddAddress.cshtml`

```
@model Address
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

Then in your editor template use

```
@Html.Action("AddAddress")
```

Comment: Uhm ok... Thank you for your answer though! 

What is really the difference of writing @Html.EditorForModel()  (or @Html.EditorFor(model => model)) when the model is a "new Address()" and writing EditorFor(m => new Address)? 

Is there really no way to accomplish this without this kind of "hacky" approach? What more specifically is blocking the call in the Api?

Comment: The difference is that EditorFor analyzes the passed in lambda expression. It rejects the one you are using with a constructor. That's simply a limitation of Mbc that we will look to address in future versions.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that clarification. I suppose I'll use your suggestion then.

Comment: with your solution the `Address` when posted back to the controller has the same `Id` as the parent object. Assuming the controller looks like `public ActionResult Add(Person person, Address address)` unless I am misunderstood something.